# Is it possible to move_upload_file to my server

Tags: php, security, file-upload

I've hosted a site on a shared hosting server.
I've a given permission 776 to a folder, is it possible for someone to upload a file using move_upload_file to my server from his home pc or own server ?

`Edit`
If i do not provide the front panel or some UI to the user is it still possible to upload file ?

Comment: you mean is it possible for someone else to upload a file on your server? i think that is the whole point of using upload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, if you do not provide a script which receives the file and moves it, some other user can't upload a file to your server.

All `move_uploaded_file` does is move a file from the temporary directory on the hard drive to a different location on the same hard drive. It cannot put files on someone else's computer.

Your question is equivalent to asking whether your next door neighbor can copy child pornography onto your home PC's hard drive over the internet. You should be happy that the answer is no.

Answer (score 3):

You use `move_uploaded_file` (note: upload*ed*) to move/rename files in your PHP scripts on your server. The special thing about `move_uploaded_file` vs. `rename` is that it will check whether the file was just uploaded in the same HTTP request. If it wasn't, it will fail with an error.

This is to prevent errors in your script or malicious users from tricking your server into moving any other sort of files around that you didn't intend to move. Using it you can be sure that you're only moving uploaded files out of the temp directory to some other destination.

That's all it does. It does not upload files to some other server. You cannot simply upload files to some other server without that server handling that upload somehow (like through a PHP script, FTP, SCP etc).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're asking exactly.

If you're saying, can you make an HTML form and have someone hit that from their browser to upload. That depends what user apache runs as.  You can make an HTML form, catch it with PHP and use `move_uploaded_file` if whatever user apache runs as can create a file in that directory.

If you're thinking someone can write a php script on another computer, and use the function `move_uploaded_file`, then no, you definitely can't.  That's not what that function does.  I'd recommend using SCP for something like that.